# Listing a single file in multiple directories with python

Tags: python, path, directory

I have found many methods to list every file in multiple directories, like so:

```
root = "C:\\test\\"
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    for name in files:
        print(os.path.join(path, name))
```

However, I need to list only one file in each directory. I am not looking for any particular order, but I do not need randomness either. Is there a way to get a single file (preferably the "first") in each directory to save the resources it would take to list every file? (This is a Windows filesystem, if that is relevant.)

Comment: the thing is you are already listing all files in the directory in order to find the subdirectories, nothing saved, you could just as well use `if files: print(files[0])`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following code:

```
import os

root = "C:\\test\\"
for path, subdirs, files in os.walk(root):
    if files:
        print(os.path.join(path, min(files)))
```

**UPDATE**

To exclude initial directory:

```
import os
import itertools

root = "C:\\test\\"
for path, subdirs, files in itertools.islice(os.walk(root), 1, None):
    if files:
        print(os.path.join(path, min(files)))
```

used [`min`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#min) to get the first (alphabetically) filename.

Comment: Perfect! While I should have included this in the original question, is there a way to easily exclude the initial directory? (List \test\test.txt, but not \test.txt)

Comment: @EpicCyndaquil, Do you want remove `C:` from `C:\test\test.txt`?

Comment: No @falsetru, perhaps my phrasing was incorrect. I do not want to see C:\test\test.txt at all, but only C:\test\test01\test01.txt, C:\test\test02\test02.txt, etc.

Comment: I'm having an issue getting it to work properly from the current directory of the script (which, when printed, returns the proper directory). The structure is identical to that of my inital test folder. Any ideas?

Comment: @EpicCyndaquil, Do you mean `root = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))` ?

Comment: Correct, @falsetru. Does the number 1 perhaps limit to a certain number of directories? There are now 4 directories (C:\1\2\3\4). The dirs on level 4 are the ones I want.

Comment: `itertools.islice(x, 1, None)` is similar to `x[1:]`.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's the issue - it's functioning completely differently now by only printing one file in a single dir at level 4 in my above comment.

Comment: @EpicCyndaquil, Do you get what you want if you replace `if files:` with `if files and path.count(os.sep) == 3:`?

Comment: it was a mistake on my part. I still need to pound the concept of not using return during a loop into my head. :)